# Connect points (route) on google map based on line boundary

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am facing a real issue trying to trace a route that will connect points, but making sure the route goes through the waypoints and follow a line boundary.

I try to be a bit more specific. In the image below, on the left we can see a green point, this is a starting point for the route I have to draw. The yellow points are the boundaries for this line, we could call that a path. On the right, I tried to draw manually what I am expecting as result.

[image]

For above, I could almost do it by using the direction service of google, however the result is not correct as sometime it wont take the expected route I want, ie. not following the boundaries.

Here is another example as sometimes the route can split into 2 paths.

[image]

Here is the code I have that display the stop points, the way points and a try to connect the points together.

If somebody has a great idea to be able to connect the points together by following the boundaries (the yellow points), that would be really nice because I have been spending already a lot of time trying to find out a solution.

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      #map-canvas {
        height: 550px;
        width: 550px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
    var boundary = [[4.398844 ,45.446252],[4.400346 ,45.446403],[4.400625 ,45.446403],[4.400625 ,45.446674],[4.400926 ,45.44696],[4.401333 ,45.447291],[4.401505 ,45.447622],[4.401591 ,45.447984],[4.401569 ,45.4483],[4.401612 ,45.448526],[4.401698 ,45.448526],[4.401698 ,45.448736],[4.401784 ,45.448992],[4.401891 ,45.449203],[4.401977 ,45.449414],[4.402235 ,45.449594],[4.402621 ,45.450467],[4.40187 ,45.450467],[4.40187 ,45.449594],[4.402621 ,45.449414],[4.402235 ,45.449203],[4.401977 ,45.449113],[4.401655 ,45.448872],[4.401248 ,45.448699],[4.400979 ,45.448699],[4.400979 ,45.448556],[4.400668 ,45.448134],[4.39996 ,45.447773],[4.399316 ,45.447562],[4.39893 ,45.447389],[4.398619 ,45.447389],[4.398619 ,45.447035],[4.397986 ,45.446674],[4.397986 ,45.445816],[4.398018 ,45.445816],[4.398018 ,45.444852],[4.398029 ,45.444626],[4.397814 ,45.44428],[4.397385 ,45.443994],[4.39717 ,45.443663],[4.39702 ,45.443452],[4.397042 ,45.443196],[4.397256 ,45.443076],[4.397385 ,45.44297],[4.39805 ,45.44285],[4.398758 ,45.44279],[4.399102 ,45.442715],[4.399649 ,45.442715],[4.399649 ,45.44279],[4.399102 ,45.442444],[4.398909 ,45.441811],[4.398587 ,45.441254],[4.399166 ,45.440802],[4.399617 ,45.440577],[4.39981 ,45.440306],[4.399853 ,45.44014],[4.399853 ,45.440035],[4.399359 ,45.439929],[4.398951 ,45.439884],[4.398651 ,45.439854],[4.398415 ,45.439749],[4.398136 ,45.439568],[4.397836 ,45.439252],[4.397492 ,45.438695],[4.396806 ,45.438476],[4.396527 ,45.438476],[4.396527 ,45.438288],[4.396291 ,45.437987],[4.395819 ,45.437761],[4.39554 ,45.43743],[4.395196 ,45.437189],[4.394853 ,45.437189],[4.394853 ,45.436587],[4.394059 ,45.436391],[4.39436 ,45.436195],[4.394531 ,45.435909],[4.394596 ,45.435653],[4.394617 ,45.435352],[4.394703 ,45.43493],[4.394853 ,45.434524],[4.395025 ,45.434117],[4.395175 ,45.433801],[4.395282 ,45.433545],[4.39539 ,45.433545],[4.39539 ,45.433214],[4.395518 ,45.432868],[4.395647 ,45.432536],[4.395776 ,45.432325],[4.395819 ,45.432145],[4.395733 ,45.431979],[4.395626 ,45.431813],[4.395475 ,45.431678],[4.395218 ,45.431271],[4.39554 ,45.431],[4.395754 ,45.430925],[4.396226 ,45.430925],[4.396226 ,45.430669],[4.397085 ,45.430413],[4.397621 ,45.430232],[4.397943 ,45.429961],[4.398372 ,45.429781],[4.398651 ,45.429464],[4.399166 ,45.429163],[4.39966 ,45.429028],[4.399939 ,45.428982],[4.400175 ,45.428998],[4.400411 ,45.428998],[4.400411 ,45.428982],[4.400175 ,45.429028],[4.399939 ,45.429163],[4.39966 ,45.429464],[4.399166 ,45.429781],[4.398651 ,45.429871],[4.398533 ,45.429871],[4.398533 ,45.429961],[4.398372 ,45.430232],[4.397943 ,45.430413],[4.397621 ,45.430669],[4.397085 ,45.431113],[4.39672 ,45.431113],[4.39672 ,45.431362],[4.39657 ,45.432009],[4.396291 ,45.432386],[4.396141 ,45.432717],[4.395969 ,45.432988],[4.395905 ,45.433199],[4.395776 ,45.433365],[4.395669 ,45.433545],[4.39539 ,45.433545],[4.39539 ,45.433801],[4.395282 ,45.434117],[4.395175 ,45.434524],[4.395025 ,45.43493],[4.394853 ,45.435352],[4.394703 ,45.435653],[4.394617 ,45.435909],[4.394596 ,45.436195],[4.394531 ,45.436391],[4.39436 ,45.436587],[4.394059 ,45.437355],[4.392922 ,45.437355],[4.392922 ,45.437505],[4.393308 ,45.437686],[4.393609 ,45.438032],[4.393995 ,45.438393],[4.394381 ,45.438755],[4.394789 ,45.438966],[4.395068 ,45.439086],[4.395239 ,45.439161],[4.395475 ,45.439222],[4.395669 ,45.439327],[4.396119 ,45.439402],[4.39642 ,45.43944],[4.396752 ,45.43944],[4.396752 ,45.439568],[4.397836 ,45.439749],[4.398136 ,45.439854],[4.398415 ,45.439884],[4.398651 ,45.439929],[4.398951 ,45.440035],[4.399359 ,45.44014],[4.399853 ,45.440396],[4.401119 ,45.440682],[4.400947 ,45.441149],[4.400668 ,45.4416],[4.400389 ,45.442052],[4.400175 ,45.442203],[4.400175 ,45.442338],[4.400175 ,45.442459],[4.400218 ,45.442579],[4.400303 ,45.442715],[4.399649 ,45.428757],[4.407513 ,45.428727],[4.407213 ,45.428546],[4.406054 ,45.428486],[4.405603 ,45.42841],[4.405174 ,45.428365],[4.404874 ,45.42841],[4.404573 ,45.428561],[4.403951 ,45.428621],[4.403672 ,45.428621],[4.403672 ,45.428561],[4.403951 ,45.42841],[4.404573 ,45.428365],[4.404874 ,45.42841],[4.405174 ,45.428486],[4.405603 ,45.428486],[4.405797 ,45.428486],[4.405797 ,45.428546],[4.406054 ,45.428727],[4.407213 ,45.428757],[4.407513 ,45.428757],[4.407513 ,45.428847],[4.407921 ,45.428982],[4.408779 ,45.429118],[4.409358 ,45.429269],[4.409745 ,45.429269],[4.409745 ,45.429058],[4.409745 ,45.428486],[4.409745 ,45.427657],[4.409766 ,45.427221],[4.409809 ,45.426874],[4.409809 ,45.426663],[4.409895 ,45.426663],[4.409895 ,45.426437],[4.409916 ,45.426136],[4.410067 ,45.425895],[4.410388 ,45.425745],[4.410732 ,45.425715],[4.411182 ,45.42576],[4.41159 ,45.42588],[4.411998 ,45.426001],[4.412363 ,45.426166],[4.412684 ,45.426302],[4.412942 ,45.426302],[4.412942 ,45.426453],[4.413178 ,45.426739],[4.413564 ,45.42701],[4.413757 ,45.427145],[4.413993 ,45.427205],[4.414272 ,45.427311],[4.414723 ,45.427461],[4.414937 ,45.427703],[4.415045 ,45.428215],[4.415367 ,45.428425],[4.415495 ,45.428425],[4.415495 ,45.42838],[4.415688 ,45.428019],[4.41659 ,45.427703],[4.417255 ,45.427386],[4.417856 ,45.427055],[4.418349 ,45.426965],[4.418521 ,45.426965],[4.418521 ,45.426874],[4.418628 ,45.426453],[4.419143 ,45.426106],[4.419551 ,45.425978],[4.41998 ,45.42579],[4.420645 ,45.425639],[4.421203 ,45.425489],[4.421611 ,45.425368],[4.421911 ,45.425157],[4.422169 ,45.425022],[4.422319 ,45.424841],[4.422534 ,45.424691],[4.422748 ,45.424691],[4.422748 ,45.42454],[4.423091 ,45.424314],[4.423542 ,45.424028],[4.424014 ,45.423787],[4.424357 ,45.423501],[4.424679 ,45.423245],[4.424937 ,45.423064],[4.425065 ,45.422868],[4.425173 ,45.422868],[4.425173 ,45.422627],[4.425302 ,45.42207],[4.425538 ,45.421573],[4.425709 ,45.421212],[4.425709 ,45.420775],[4.42558 ,45.420504],[4.425452 ,45.420293],[4.42528 ,45.420293],[4.42528 ,45.420187],[4.425194 ,45.419886],[4.424894 ,45.41966],[4.424529 ,45.419118],[4.423585 ,45.418968],[4.423327 ,45.41823],[4.422019 ,45.418164],[4.421827 ,45.452229],[4.399509 ,45.452063],[4.39981 ,45.451642],[4.400454 ,45.45125],[4.401033 ,45.450904],[4.401441 ,45.450753],[4.401612 ,45.450467],[4.40187 ,45.429269],[4.409745 ,45.429382],[4.409992 ,45.429374],[4.410399 ,45.429389],[4.411054 ,45.429351],[4.411697 ,45.429186],[4.412781 ,45.429035],[4.413596 ,45.428794],[4.414433 ,45.428576],[4.415141 ,45.428425],[4.415495 ,45.467836],[4.397492 ,45.467595],[4.397664 ,45.467279],[4.397793 ,45.467038],[4.39805 ,45.466775],[4.398415 ,45.466564],[4.398726 ,45.466421],[4.398887 ,45.466196],[4.398887 ,45.46591],[4.39893 ,45.465654],[4.39893 ,45.465428],[4.398887 ,45.465428],[4.398887 ,45.465052],[4.398801 ,45.464766],[4.39863 ,45.464405],[4.398394 ,45.464029],[4.398222 ,45.463592],[4.398007 ,45.463261],[4.397857 ,45.463261],[4.397857 ,45.46278],[4.397643 ,45.462027],[4.397278 ,45.46153],[4.397042 ,45.461275],[4.396935 ,45.460988],[4.396827 ,45.460988],[4.396827 ,45.460597],[4.396634 ,45.460371],[4.396484 ,45.46001],[4.396291 ,45.459634],[4.396162 ,45.459453],[4.396076 ,45.459198],[4.39584 ,45.458776],[4.395347 ,45.458535],[4.395068 ,45.458535],[4.395068 ,45.458264],[4.394724 ,45.458039],[4.39436 ,45.457843],[4.394038 ,45.457617],[4.393673 ,45.457467],[4.393394 ,45.457467],[4.393394 ,45.457301],[4.393072 ,45.457015],[4.392643 ,45.456759],[4.392343 ,45.456383],[4.392021 ,45.455976],[4.391763 ,45.455555],[4.391549 ,45.454998],[4.391313 ,45.454381],[4.391012 ,45.45402],[4.390883 ,45.45402],[4.390883 ,45.453568],[4.390701 ,45.453553],[4.391205 ,45.453628],[4.391881 ,45.453734],[4.392471 ,45.453869],[4.393158 ,45.45399],[4.393866 ,45.45405],[4.394467 ,45.45405],[4.394467 ,45.45411],[4.395132 ,45.454163],[4.396699 ,45.4542],[4.39717 ,45.45414],[4.397514 ,45.454005],[4.397943 ,45.453689],[4.398694 ,45.453523],[4.399016 ,45.453523],[4.399016 ,45.453282],[4.398909 ,45.453056],[4.398823 ,45.45268],[4.39878 ,45.45256],[4.399016 ,45.452424],[4.399273 ,45.452229],[4.399509 ,45.472531],[4.399102 ,45.47214],[4.399359 ,45.471342],[4.399724 ,45.471026],[4.39996 ,45.47077],[4.400346 ,45.471011],[4.400711 ,45.471583],[4.401527 ,45.472004],[4.40217 ,45.471703],[4.402642 ,45.471523],[4.402835 ,45.471523],[4.402835 ,45.471703],[4.402642 ,45.472004],[4.40217 ,45.471583],[4.401527 ,45.471011],[4.400711 ,45.47077],[4.400346 ,45.470913],[4.40011 ,45.470913],[4.40011 ,45.471026],[4.39996 ,45.471342],[4.399724 ,45.47214],[4.399359 ,45.472531],[4.399102 ,45.472531],[4.399102 ,45.472877],[4.39893 ,45.473449],[4.398673 ,45.47399],[4.398565 ,45.474487],[4.398436 ,45.474788],[4.398254 ,45.474916],[4.398018 ,45.474969],[4.397643 ,45.474863],[4.397224 ,45.474683],[4.396999 ,45.474336],[4.396784 ,45.473855],[4.396527 ,45.473163],[4.396226 ,45.47279],[4.396143 ,45.47279],[4.396143 ,45.472456],[4.396076 ,45.471778],[4.395948 ,45.471162],[4.395797 ,45.470695],[4.395754 ,45.470274],[4.395754 ,45.470274],[4.395754 ,45.469898],[4.395776 ,45.469416],[4.395948 ,45.468965],[4.396205 ,45.468679],[4.396462 ,45.468453],[4.396741 ,45.468242],[4.397042 ,45.468062],[4.397299 ,45.467836],[4.397492 ,45.428998],[4.400411 ,45.428975],[4.40084 ,45.428967],[4.402084 ,45.428967],[4.402342 ,45.428877],[4.402707 ,45.428711],[4.40335 ,45.428621],[4.403672 ,45.445266]];
    var points = [  
    ['4', '3', '45.426663388885', '4.4098949432373', '43, Le Corbusier', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['5', '3', '45.426301960728', '4.4129419326782', '57, Le Corbusier', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['160', '3', '45.429261085673', '4.4097447395325', 'Beaulieu', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['477', '3', '45.428417788517', '4.4155061244965', 'Centre Commercial Montchovet', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['1030', '3', '45.422868277819', '4.4251728057861', 'Faculté des Sciences', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['1772', '3', '45.424690565371', '4.4227588176727', 'L\'Angélus', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['1785', '3', '45.429870962373', '4.3985331058502', 'Lassaigne', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['2371', '3', '45.428485553932', '4.4057965278625', 'Liogier', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['2396', '3', '45.428621084519', '4.4036722183228', 'Louis Blanc', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['2563', '3', '45.426964577248', '4.4185209274292', 'Marandinière', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['2713', '3', '45.42029287858', '4.4252908229828', 'Nicolas Mignard', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['2829', '3', '45.428749085331', '4.4075131416321', 'Pierre Blachon', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['3167', '3', '45.428997556665', '4.4004213809967', 'Résidence Guinard', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['34356', '3', '45.452228557408', '4.3995094299316', 'AFPA', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['34997', '3', '45.438476297658', '4.3965268135071', 'Chantegrillet', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['35202', '3', '45.467835981334', '4.3974924087524', 'Claudius Petit', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['35318', '3', '45.446402886221', '4.4006252288818', 'Collège Vallès', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['35341', '3', '45.430925054711', '4.3962264060974', 'Conservatoire', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['35478', '3', '45.472523384943', '4.3991017341614', 'Debussy', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['35728', '3', '45.43943989305', '4.3967521190643', 'Fourneyron', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['35936', '3', '45.470905785694', '4.400110244751', 'Georges Bizet', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['36075', '3', '45.46542817465', '4.3988978862762', 'Gustave Delory', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['36246', '3', '45.437354591671', '4.3929219245911', 'Jean Moulin', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['36700', '3', '45.460980986303', '4.3968272209167', 'Le Bessard', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['36806', '3', '45.458535259453', '4.395078420639', 'Le Marais', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['37262', '3', '45.445815769704', '4.3980181217194', 'Louis Soulié', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['37264', '3', '45.445258756078', '4.3988442420959', 'Louis Soulié', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['37309', '3', '45.437188968764', '4.3948531150818', 'Lycée Fauriel', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['37722', '3', '45.472786710659', '4.396151304245', 'Offenbach', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['38016', '3', '45.44869107689', '4.4009900093079', 'Place Dumay', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['38019', '3', '45.448525487259', '4.4016981124878', 'Place Dumay', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['38054', '3', '45.433537612998', '4.3954002857208', 'Place Villeboeuf', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['38240', '3', '45.457459106031', '4.3934047222137', 'Productique', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['38508', '3', '45.454019792709', '4.3908834457397', 'Rue des Acieries', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['38537', '3', '45.431113283414', '4.3967199325562', 'Rue Emile', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['38755', '3', '45.453523069292', '4.3990159034729', 'Scheurer Kestner', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['38793', '3', '45.450467371436', '4.4018805027008', 'Soleil', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['38917', '3', '45.447381400169', '4.3986189365387', 'Tiblier Verne', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['39041', '3', '45.4632610607', '4.3978679180145', 'Victor Grignard', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['39078', '3', '45.470273780817', '4.3957543373108', 'Vivaldi', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538'],
    ['39108', '3', '45.454049897017', '4.3944776058197', 'Zénith', '3', 'STAS-9:9', '', '1', '3', '3', 'Saint-Étienne', '42000', '4.3924', '45.4538']   
    ];
    var stops = [
    [ 45.442669323228, 4.3996810913086, "Ch\u00e2teaucreux" ],
    [ 45.418093906726, 4.4219970703125, "M\u00e9tare" ],
    [ 45.47144749852, 4.4029426574707, "Montreynaud" ]
    ];
    var directionsDisplay = [];
    var directionsService = [];

function drawRouteMap(map,locations) {

    var start, end;
    var waypts = [];

    for (var k = 0; k < locations.length; k++) {
        if (k >= 1 && k <= locations.length - 2) {
            waypts.push({
                location: locations[k],
                stopover: false
            });
        }
        if (k == 0) start = locations[k];

        if (k == locations.length - 1) end = locations[k];

    }
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: false,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    console.log(request);

    directionsService.push(new google.maps.DirectionsService());
    var instance = directionsService.length - 1;
    directionsDisplay.push(new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        preserveViewport: true
    }));
    directionsDisplay[instance].setMap(map);
    directionsService[instance].route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            console.log(status);
            directionsDisplay[instance].setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.64686, 3.873507),
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    stop1 = new google.maps.Marker({            
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(stops[0][0], stops[0][1]),
        map: map,
        icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 5.5,
            fillColor: "green",
            fillOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 0.4
        },
        title: stops[0][2]
    });
    stop2 = new google.maps.Marker({            
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(stops[1][0], stops[1][1]),
        map: map,
        icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 5.5,
            fillColor: "green",
            fillOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 0.4
        },
        title: stops[1][2]
    });
    stop3 = new google.maps.Marker({            
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(stops[2][0], stops[2][1]),
        map: map,
        icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 5.5,
            fillColor: "green",
            fillOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 0.4
        },
        title: stops[2][2]
    });

  var shape = {
    coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
    type: 'poly'
  };
  // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
  var rendererOptions = {
    map: map,
    suppressMarkers: true
  }
    // Display the line bounds
    for(var i = 0; i < boundary.length; i++) {
        var myLatLon = new google.maps.LatLng(boundary[i][1], boundary[i][0]);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({           
            position: myLatLon,
            map: map,
            icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                scale: 5.5,
                fillColor: "yellow",
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 0.4
            },
            title: ""
        });
    }   
    //Map bounds
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();    
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
    var locations = new Array();
    //Displaying stops
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        console.log(points[i][2] + ',' + points[i][3]);
        var myLatLon = new google.maps.LatLng(points[i][2], points[i][3]);
        locations.push(myLatLon);   
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({           
            position: myLatLon,
            map: map,
            icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                scale: 5.5,
                fillColor: "#F00",
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 0.4
            },
            title: points[i][4]
        });
        bounds.extend(myLatLon);
    }   
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    //Trying to connect all those points
    var i = locations.length;
    var index = 0;
    while (i != 0) {

        if ( i < 2) {
            console.log("before :i < 2: i value " + i + " index value" + index);
            var tmp_locations = new Array();
            for (var j = index; j < locations.length; j++) {
                tmp_locations.push(locations[j]);
            }
            drawRouteMap(map,tmp_locations);
            i = 0;
            index = locations.length;
            console.log("after fun < 10: i value " + i + " index value" + index);
        }

        if (i >= 2) {
            console.log("before :i >= 2: i value " + i + " index value" + index);
            var tmp_locations = new Array();
            for (var j = index; j < index + 2; j++) {
                tmp_locations.push(locations[j]);
            }
            drawRouteMap(map,tmp_locations);
            i = i - 1;
            index = index + 1;
            console.log("after i >= 2: i value " + i + " index value" + index);
        }
    }   
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="map-warn"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you draw a polyline with your points?

Comment: Because it must follow the real route

Comment: What do you mean by provide the right points? The points I have are the one I have in the example, nothing else, nothing more.

Comment: I think you dont get what is the problem. The yellow points are not placed on the road all the time, which means connecting them wont show a correct route. And connecting the red one together wont be correct too. In other words, I am trying to find a solution to connect the red points together using the Google Direction service and knowing that the route should be following the yellow points (my route boundary)

Comment: Have a look at [Direction Waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints). You are limited to 8 waypoints per request though (23 with the API for Work customers).

Comment: Definitely had a look already. Do you think it is possible to find out waypoints that could match the split of the path in my second image and tell google "please make the road goes by those yellow path"?

Comment: I'm starting to think it is impossible with the info I have.